# Parsing XML (Grabbing certain data)

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have a lot of data in an XML file that I need to get out. Currently there is around 1000 pieces of data I need to extract It looks like this

http://pastebin.com/PwfhtbDF

I need to somehow extract just ip="83.42.146.140" out of every one of these. Remember there is around 1000 of these (44000 lines in total). I have tried XML parsing programs but couldn't get it to extract what I want. I was thinking about doing it in PHP somehow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) a try. SimpleXML is built into PHP.

[This is about it's basic usage (with examples)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: Is there possibly something similar that is non PHP? Something like a program? I cant install anything onto my PHP right now. Thanks for the suggestion tho!

Answer (score 0):

$result =~ /\b(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})\b/sg);

This is what I ended up using in PHP to grab all the IP's and print them out :). Thanks for all of your help.